# Remove "Calculate Shipping" Button if item is using flat rate

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

We have some items in our store that use flat rate shipping. When these items are in the cart, we don't want the "Calculate Shipping" button to show. However, if there are items in the cart that need to calculate, we want it to show.

Is there a way to remove this button using a conditional?

I was trying to loop through the cart items and test for a shipping class in the cart, but it's not working. It ended up removing the shipping cost and keeping the calculate shipping button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On that condition

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_needs_shipping', function(){return false;});
```

This will stop the calculate button. Otherwise there is no direct hook. You may endup editing your woocommerce theme and editing 'cart\shipping-calculator.php' and applying a logic there. Say you can place your own hook/filter there and set true/false from your outside code.

Comment: Hi, thanks. We ended up making the products "virtual" and including the shipping cost in the product price. 

I will try your answer though. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

WooCommerce > Settings > Shipping > Deselect “Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page”

i found this on kriesi dot at https://kriesi.at/support/topic/how-to-remove-calculate-shipping/

Comment: but this will deactivate shipping calculator for all product, even if the specified one.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to add the following CSS:

```
.shipping-calculator-button {
    display:none;
}
```